# Returning a string after the second occurrence of a character and before the last occurrence of the same character with php

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos

I have several strings similar to the following:
ORG-000012 – Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack – $14.95

I need to remove all characters before the second hyphen and after the last hyphen with php. For example, the string above needs to return as:
Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack

I have tried to use strpos and substr but I can't seem to get the correct setup. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), splitting by `–`. Then, get the second and third elements:

```
<?php
$description = "ORG-000012 – Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack – $14.95";
$descriptionArray = explode(" – ", $description);
$finalDescription = $descriptionArray[1]." – ".$descriptionArray[2];
var_dump($finalDescription); // string(39) "Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/85LeU)

Or, if the number of elements in between is variable, [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) the array to remove the first and last elements:

```
<?php
$description = "ORG-000012 – Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack – $14.95";
$descriptionArray = explode(" – ", $description);
array_pop($descriptionArray);
array_shift($descriptionArray);
var_dump($descriptionArray);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ErLrm)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the position of the first occurrence of `-` char using `strpos` and find the position of the last occurrence ot it using `strrpos`:

```
$s = 'ORG-000012 - Name of variation - Quantity: 12 Pack - $14.95';
$sub = substr($s,strpos($s, '-')+1, strrpos($s, '-')-strlen($s));
print $sub; // or print trim($sub) to remove the whitespaces
```

What it does is, it will print a substrinig of `$s` starting from one character after the first occurrence of `-` character, and omitting characters from last occurrence of `-` by passing a negative value (difference of total length of the string and position of last occurrence of `-` character) as length to `substr`.

Please note, this will print the space character before the last `-` as well, so you might want to `trim` the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible with a reg expr, try with:

```
preg_match(
    '/(?<=\s–\s)(.*)(?:\s–\s)[^\s]+$/',
    'ORG-000012 – Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack – $14.95',
    $matches
);
echo $matches[1]; //Name of variation – Quantity: 12 Pack
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explode the string into an array then pick through the pieces.

Remove the first two sequences of non-hyphen characters followed by a hyphen then a space and remove the last occurrence of a space, hyphen, then non-hyphen characters at the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ku9L9))

```
$s = 'ORG-000012 - Name of variation - Quantity: 12 Pack - $14.95';

echo preg_replace('/^(?:[^-]+-){2} | -[^-]+$/', '', $s);
```